# Ionic : how to have multiple tabs on the same template?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I would like to have multiple ion tabs which points on the same view with just a parameter change in the URL.

I don't manage to do that, the page loads, when I click on both tab, the browser loads /tab/dash/all...

HTML:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="All" icon="icon ion-grid" href="#/tab/dash/all">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-articles-all"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="New" icon="icon ion-wand" href="#/tab/dash/new">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-articles-new"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

JS:

```
$stateProvider
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash/:filter',
  views: {
    'tab-articles-all': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    },
    'tab-articles-new': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }}
  })
```

HTML:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the names of the filter parameters then why not just create separate states for each of them? Looking at your example markup you should be able to have a state config like so.

```
$stateProvider
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.dash-all', {
  url: '/dash/all',
  views: {
    'tab-articles-all': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.dash-new', {
  url: '/dash/new/',
  views: {
    'tab-articles-new': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

If you won't know all of the possible `:filter` parameters when the app starts. You can add in states on the fly by using $stateNotFound event to capture the parameters, then create a state based off the params and `go` to it.